# API Kong - How to set custom error message?

Tags: api, kong

I am not very familiar with Kong and things about it. I just want to ask, if it is possible to modify error message in the following situation.

Valid API URL for some request is e.g.

```
example.com/api/somerequest
```

If I want to make request to some invalid url e.g.

```
example.com/api/adffgdsfgfa
```

I will get this error message

```
"request_path": "/api/adffgdsfgfa",
"message": "API not found with these values"
```

I would like to replace this default message (API not found...) with my custom message. Could someone help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't explored already - you can use "exit-transformer" plugin for the same.
https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/exit-transformer/